# Fourier regression using FFTW in C

Tags: c, regression, fft, fftw

I tried to make Fourier regression using the FFTW library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

int main() {
    int n = 100;
    double y[n];
    double dt = 0.01;
    double t[n];
    double a0, a[n/2], b[n/2];
    int i;
// Generate data
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t[i] = i * dt;
    y[i] = sin(2 * PI * 0.5 * t[i]) + sin(2 * PI * 2 * t[i]);
}

// Create FFTW plan
fftw_complex* in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * n);
fftw_complex* out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * n);
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(n, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

// Load data into input array and perform FFT
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    in[i][0] = y[i];
    in[i][1] = 0.0;
}
fftw_execute(p);

// Extract Fourier coefficients
a0 = out[0][0] / n;
for (i = 1; i < n/2; i++) {
    a[i] = 2.0 * out[i][0] / n;
    b[i] = -2.0 * out[i][1] / n;
}

// Generate regression line
double y_reg[n];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    y_reg[i] = a0;
    for (int j = 1; j < n/2; j++) {
        y_reg[i] += a[j] * cos(2 * PI * j * t[i] / n) + b[j] * sin(2 * PI * j * t[i] / n);
    }
}

// Print data and regression line
printf("t\ty\ty_reg\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", t[i], y[i], y_reg[i]);
}

// Free memory and destroy plan
fftw_destroy_plan(p);
fftw_free(in);
fftw_free(out);

return 0;
}
```

but the regression does not match the input data. Where did I do wrong?

*Edit: typical output*

```
// printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", t[i], y[i], y_reg[i]);
0.300000    0.221232    0.041583
0.310000    0.142533    0.043084
0.320000    0.073815    0.044592
0.330000    0.016414    0.046106
0.340000    -0.028520   0.047628
0.350000    -0.060050   0.049156
0.360000    -0.077460   0.050690
0.370000    -0.080272   0.052231
0.380000    -0.068250   0.053778
0.390000    -0.041406   0.055331
0.400000    -0.000000   0.056890
0.410000    0.055467    0.058456
0.420000    0.124255    0.060027
0.430000    0.205404    0.061604
0.440000    0.297740    0.063186
0.450000    0.399903    0.064774
```

Comment: Tip: to debug such problems, consider `"%g"` instead of `"%f"`.  It is more informative.

Comment: "but the regression does not match the input data." --> what is some of the expected and mis-matched output you saw?

Comment: Reiterating what chux said: it is important for us to understand why you think the results are wrong, comparing expected and obtained values often leads to a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica by not match. I mean, not correlating at all, not that the fitting is not perfect.

Comment: @Googlebot by "some of the expected and mis-matched output" I mean info like "0.300000    0.221232    0.041583" - which looks like your true output .  Still looking for expect: Did you expect _exactly_ "0.300000    0.221232    0.221232"?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica not exactly being equal, but they should be very close. Note that the input is a simple and regular sine wave. FFT is meant to solve even irregular waves.

Comment: @Googlebot Why not also post the exact expected output (as requested) to improve clarity of your goal?  _should be very close_ is iffy.

Comment: @Googlebot BTW, input is not a _simple and regular sine wave_, it is sum of 2 sine waves with `sin(2 * PI * 0.5 * t[i]) + sin(2 * PI * 2 * t[i]);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, it is a simple regular two-periodic wave, as compared with the Fourier series. I expect the regression to fully match with the input at the %f precision (0.000001). I believe it is possible to reach this accuracy for such regular input. The problem is not the accuracy here. There should be a stupid mistake in the code.

Comment: Your calculation of `y_reg` looks completely wrong to me, but I don't have time to debug it right now.

Comment: @PaulR could you please give me a hit where it seems off to you?

Comment: Could it be that the "fftw_plan_dft_1d" must be executed after the assignments of values to in[][] ?

Comment: @S_IROTH no, that's not an issue. Before `fftw_execute`, the data is not read.

Comment: @Googlebot: well I don’t think the t[i] term should be in there, for one thing, but it doesn’t seem to match the equation for the inverse DFT, which is presumably what you’re trying to do ?